# Python usage of os.renames

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-rename

I am trying to rename files using python but I cannot figure exactly where is the error, perhaps I am too tired as trying to do this for over 30 hours non-stopping.

The actual problem is quite visible when you look at the **desired output** and in the ***actual*** one.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os
import glob
if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_file=sys.argv[1]
    File= open(input_file)
    while True:
       line=File.readline()
       words = line.split()
       if not ("call" or "song") in words:
         break 
       folder_dest= words[0] +" "+ words[1]
       subfolder=words[3]
       filename=words[4].replace(".wav","")
       folder_now=words[7].replace(".wav","")
       os.chdir(folder_now)
       i=1
       for files in glob.glob("*.wav"): 
           os.renames(files,"../"+folder_dest+"/"+subfolder+"/"+filename+"-"+'{:03}'.format(i)+".wav")
           i+=1
       os.chdir("..")
```

**More explanation:**

I have this input file

```
Aegolius harrisii song 10009.wav Aegolius harrisii song 21.wav
Aegolius harrisii song 483_Aegolius%20harrisii_F27_Itatira_28_IV_2004_Weber%20Girao.wav Aegolius harrisii song 22.wav
Gnorimopsar chopi song 1000517.wav Gnorimopsar chopi song 825.wav
Myiobius barbatus call Myiobius.sulphureipygius9402-1.wav Myiobius barbatus call 1146.wav
Myiobius barbatus song 1001.wav Myiobius barbatus song 1147.wav
Muscipipra vetula call 1000682.wav Muscipipra vetula call 1122.wav
```

This is the current folder structure:

```
1
├── parte_1.wav
└── parte_2.wav

2
├── parte_1.wav
├── parte_2.wav
├── parte_3.wav
├── parte_4.wav
├── parte_5.wav
└── parte_6.wav
```

...

Here is the output as now:

```
Aegolius harrisii/
    ├── 100015.wav
    │   ├── Aegolius-001.wav
    │   └── Aegolius-002.wav
    └──  AEGOLI~1.wav
        ├── Aegolius-001.wav
        ├── Aegolius-002.wav
        ├── Aegolius-003.wav
        ├── Aegolius-004.wav
        ├── Aegolius-005.wav
        └── Aegolius-006.wav
```

desired output

```
Aegolius harrisii/
├── call
│   ├── 100015-001.wav
│   └── 100015-002.wav
└── song
    ├──  AEGOLI~1-001.wav
    ├──  AEGOLI~1-002.wav
    ├──  AEGOLI~1-003.wav
    ├──  AEGOLI~1-004.wav
    ├──  AEGOLI~1-005.wav
    └──  AEGOLI~1-006.wav
```

The question is: what I'am doing wrong in os.renames?

Thank you, for reading/answering this!

Comment: The way you entered your input file caused all the lines to be run together. I've edited it to what I think you wanted, bug please verify that it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is obvious if you just print out `words`:

```
['Aegolius', 'harrisii', 'song', '10009.wav', 'Aegolius', 'harrisii', 'song', '21.wav']
```

You're setting `subfolder=words[3]`, which is `10009.wav` rather than `song`. You wanted the third word, which is `words[2]` (because Python is 0-based).

Likewise, you're setting `filename=words[4]` instead of `words[3]`, which is `Aegolius` rather than `10009.wav`.

I think you have `folder_now` correct—it's `21.wav`.

---

The second problem is that `if not ("call" or "song") in words` doesn't do what you want. `("call" or "song")` is just `"call"`. So, you're stopping as soon as you reach a line with `song` in it.

You probably wanted this:

```
if not ("call" in words or "song" in words):
```

… or maybe:

```
if not {"call", "song"}.intersection(words):
```

---

A third possible problem (I don't know if this is affecting you) is that you use `break` instead of `continue`, which means you stop at the first invalid line, instead of just skipping over invalid lines.

---

While we're at it, a few minor ways you could improve your code:

- Be consistent with your indentation. Your source mixes tabs and spaces, which is a recipe for disaster; you're lucky you got away with it. You also use different amounts of indentation everywhere—two spaces, three spaces, four spaces, one tab, etc.—which makes your code hard to read. Find yourself an editor that takes care of this for you (whether that's IDLE, a fancy IDE like Visual Studio or Eclipse, a nice "programmer's text editor" like BBEdit, or even emacs).
- Instead of doing `while True:` and `line=File.readline()`, you can just do `for line in File:`.
- Don't try to `os.chdir` down and back up. You'll leave things in a funky state if you fail or cancel in the middle, you'll run into problems with symlinks, etc. You can just use paths, like `for files in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_now, "*.wav"))`.
- Use `os.path` functions instead of trying to treat paths as strings.
- Don't try to maintain an explicit counter by setting `i=1` and doing `i+=1` each time through the loop; just use `enumerate`.
- Use consistent naming conventions.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer, specially all the suggestions to improve my code.